# html form action attribute always send the form data to the server side?

Tags: html, forms

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp), the **Definition and Usage** of form `action`is described as follows:

> The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form
>   is submitted.

My question is, the form data will always send to the service side by using action attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a form is to package up a bunch of data from inputs (and selects etc) into an HTTP request.

HTTP requests are sent to a server.

The action attribute tells the browser what URL to use for that.

---

You can interfere (in all sorts of ways, including preventing submission entirely) with normal form behaviour using JavaScript.

HTML 5 introduces [the `formaction` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formaction) for overriding a form's action when a specific submit button is used.

Comment: ok, so the action always means the action in the server side, thanks !